# Can I customize logs in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am a JMeter learner and you are supporting me to learn. I am very grateful to all.

I just wanted to know if I can customize the log columns. By default they are:

- TimeStamp        - unix timestamp of the request
- elapsed          - time elapsed
- label            - a label (page title or url)
- responseCode     - http response code
- responseMessage  - http response message
- threadName       - name of the jave thread that did the request
- dataType         - mime type of the response
- success          - boolean, true if request successful
- bytes            - size of the response body
- Latency          - latency in ms

eg: Can I display date instead of Timestamp in my log file?

Comment: I'm not into JMeter but maybe this helps you: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FFWTutorials/

Comment: Don't know why do you want to modify the logs when you can use Listeners to interpret them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, it is controllable by the following property:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
```

It defaults to milliseconds since beginning of [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

If you want to change the format, any valid [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) value will play, for instance `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Add `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` to *user.properties* file (it's located under JMeter's /bin folder) and after JMeter restart you'll see different timestamps.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more detailed information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.

Comment: I used Your answer and gets proper output what i was expecting

Answer (score 1):

Please go thru this link:

[Can any one explain how the Jmeter listeners work](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13999/can-any-one-explain-how-the-jmeter-listeners-work)

It will explain you how listeners in general work and how the log file is interpreted by the listeners.

Comment: I think it should be comment.

Comment: 1449057501605,3168,femur-bone-model( Product Page),503,Service Unavailable,Thread Group 1-90,text,false,1593,100,100,3167

What is this error indicates????